# Uncompilable Source Code: Erroneous Sym Error

Tags: java

I've been looking at ways to fix this all over the internet and can't really find anything that I understand. I'm doing a tutorial and copying out everything that my teacher has typed, so I'm just learning.. but when I did this it kept giving me this error. Since I'm new to this I have no idea what the heck it means or how to fix it :(

```
public final class DefaultPlayerNameConverter
        implements PlayerNameConverter
{

    /**
     * Must be created through the create method.
     */
    private DefaultPlayerNameConverter()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Create a DefaultPlayerNameConverter.
     * 
     * @return a DefaultPlayerNameCOnverter.
     */
    public static DefaultPlayerNameConverter create()
    {
        final DefaultPlayerNameConverter converter;

        converter = new DefaultPlayerNameConverter();

        return (converter);
    }

    /**
     * Convert player name to remove leading/trailing whitespace.
     * 
     * @param name the name to convert.
     * 
     * @return the converted name.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if name is null.
     */
    @Override
    public String convertName(final String name)
    {
        final String convertedName;

        if(name == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name cannot be null");
        }

        convertedName = name.trim();

        return (convertedName);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DefaultPlayerNameConverterTest {

    public DefaultPlayerNameConverterTest() {
    }

    /**
     * Test bad arguments to the convertName method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testConvertBadName() 
    {
        try
        {
            new DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create().convertName(null);
            fail("convertName(null) must throw an "
                    + "IllegalArgumentException");
        }
        catch(final IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {
            assertEquals("name cannot be null", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

        /**
         * Test good arguments to the convertName method.
         */
        @Test
        public void testConvertGoodName()
        {
            checkConvertName("", "");
            checkConvertName("\t", "");
            checkConvertName("\n", "");
            checkConvertName("\r", "");
            checkConvertName("\r\n", "");
            checkConvertName("\r\n\t", "");
            checkConvertName("X", "X");
            checkConvertName(" X", "X");
            checkConvertName("X ", "X");
            checkConvertName(" X ", "X");
            checkConvertName("X Y", "X Y");
            checkConvertName("Hello\tworld", "Hello\tworld");
        }
        /**
         * Check that the name conversion works.
         * 
         * @param originalName the name to convert.
         * @param expectedName what the name should be converted to.
         */
        private void checkConvertName(final String originalName, 
                                      final String expectedName)
        {
            final PlayerNameConverter converter;
            final String convertedName;

            converter = new DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create();
            convertedName = converter.convertName(originalName);
            assertEquals(expectedName, convertedName);

        }
}
```

The error keeps showing up in my test class when I added the "DefaultPlayerNameConverter create" method. I have no idea how to fix it. I just put what the tutorial told me to do.

---

This is the PlayerNameConverter interface...

```
public interface PlayerNameConverter {

    /**
     * Convert the supplied name.
     * 
     * @param name the name to convert.
     * 
     * @return the converted name.
     */
    String convertName(String name);
}
```

Comment: What is the error, precisely?  Copy it exactly.

Comment: My bet are the final keywords for converter and converterName. Sorry no IDE on phone.

Comment: Have you got the PlayerNameConverter interface too?

Comment: Whenever I try to run the test class I get this error:

cannot find symbol
symbol  : class create

It seems to be happening for anything that has ".create()" added to it

Comment: Try using `javac` from the command line.

Comment: Okay when I did that I got:

cannot find symbol : method asserEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class DefaultPlayerNameConverterTest assertEquals("name cannot be null", ex.getMessage());

cannot find symbol
symbol : class PlayerNameConverter
location: class DefaultPlayerNameConverterTest
          final PlayerNameConverter converter;
                ^

package DefaultPlayerNameConverter does not exist
        converter = new DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create();

Comment: cannot find symber
symbol: method assertEquals(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
location: class DefaultPlayerNameConverterTest
          assertEquals(expectedName, convertName);

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
new DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create().convertName(null);
```

shouldn't have the `new` keyword, it should just be

```
DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create().convertName(null);
```

Comment: I tried that just now. It doesn't seem to be working. It still says that it "cannot find symbol" whenever I have DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create() or something close to that.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. Changed my answer entirely, check it again.

Comment: That fixed everything!! Thank you so much!!